# For this $\phi,$ if $\phi(u)>a$, there exists open $U$ s.t. $\phi(v)>a$ for all $v$. Relating to continuity.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$X$ : Banach space

$Y$ : norm space with norm $\| \cdot \|_Y$

$A$ : continuous and linear operator from $X$ to $Y$

Define $\phi : X\to \mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto \| Ax \|_Y$.

Then, $\phi$ is continuous since $A$ is continuous and operating the norm is continuous.

---

Let $u\in X$, and suppose there exists $a\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $\phi(u)>a$.

Then, prove that there exists an open set $U\subset X$ s.t. $$\phi(v)>a \ \mathrm{for \ all \ } v\in U.$$

---

I think this is relatve to general topology and can be proved by continuity of $\phi$, but my try doesn't work.

Let $N$ be a neighbourhood of $\phi (u)$, i.e., $\phi(u)\in N^i$.

Since $\phi$ is continuous at $u$, $\phi^{-1}(N)$ is a neighbourhood of $u$, i.e., $u\in [\phi^{-1}(N)]^i$.

Let $U:=[\phi^{-1}(N)]^i.$

Does this $U$ work ? I cannot show $\|A v\|>a$ for all $v\in U.$

If $v\in U=[\phi^{-1}(N)]^i$ then $\phi(v)\in N$ but does this lead to $\|A v\|>a$ ?

Or, am I on the wrong track ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just take $N=(a,\infty)$ and $U=\phi^{-1}(N)$.

Comment: Exact answer. Thank you. @geetha290krm